# Use a button in a forms to append variables to an url which has variables from another forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a site with a search bar and some checkboxes, these add variables to the url:

```
term = "test"
variable1=1
url/search?term=test&variable1=1
```

Then, after that search is complete I have another forms to the left of the page with some other checkboxes and another search button. I want that button, when clicked, to run another search with the old search term and variables but with the new ones added

```
othervariable=1
url/search?term=test&variable1=1&othervariable=1
```

I have tried some suggestions from other threads but the second search button appears to only add the variable to the url

```
url/othervariable=1
```

which does not work for this

first forms:

```html
    <form id="search_form" method="get" name="search">
      <div class="input-group row" style="width: 40vw ">
        {% if termo %}
          <input style="border-radius: 0; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);" type="text" maxlength="1800" id="input_text" name="termo_busca" class="form-control" value="{{ termo }}"/>
        {% else %}
          <input style="border-radius: 0; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);" type="text" name="termo_busca" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o termo que deseja pesquisar"/>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button style="background-color: #4A9FFF; border-color: #4A9FFF; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 0; padding: 0.85rem 1.05rem; font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.25;" onclick="changeFlag()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Buscar"> 
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group row" style="width: 44vw">
        <!-- <label style="font-size: 12px;">Cortes :</label> -->
        <label class="checkbox-inline" style="font-size: 11px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);">
          <input type="checkbox" name="recursal" value="1" {% if "recursal" in courts %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}> Recursal
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline" style="font-size: 11px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);">
          <input type="checkbox"  name="constitucional" value="1" {% if "constitucional" in courts %} checked {% else %} {% endif %} > Constitucional
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline" style="font-size: 11px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);">
          <input type="checkbox" name="reclamacao" value="1" {% if "reclamacao" in courts %} checked {% else %} {% endif %} > Reclamacao
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline" style="font-size: 11px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);">
          <input type="checkbox" name="habeas_corpus" value="1" {% if "habeas_corpus" in courts %} checked {% else %} {% endif %} > Habeas Corpus
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline" style="font-size: 11px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);">
          <input type="checkbox" name="mandado_seguranca" value="1" {% if "mandado_seguranca" in courts %} checked {% else %} {% endif %} > Mandado Seguranca
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline" style="font-size: 11px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);">
          <input type="checkbox" name="penal_original" value="1" {% if "penal_original" in courts %} checked {% else %} {% endif %} > Penal Original
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline" style="font-size: 11px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);">
          <input type="checkbox" name="outros" value="1" {% if "outros" in courts %} checked {% else %} {% endif %} > Outros
        </label>

        <!-- <label class="checkbox-inline" style="font-size: 11px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);">
          <input type="checkbox" name="todos" value="1" {% if todos == None %} {% else %} checked {% endif %} checked> Todos
        </label> -->

      </div>

      {% if total %}
      <strong style="font-size: 13px;"></strong>
      {% elif termo %}
        <strong style="font-size: 13px;">Não foram encontradas decisões relacionadas ao termo {{ termo }}.</strong> <br/><br/>
      {% endif %}
    </form>
```

second forms:

```html
        <form id="diogo_form" method="get" name="search" ; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);">
          <div class="dropdown" data-control="checkbox-dropdown">
              <label class="dropdown-option">
                <input type="checkbox" name="selecone" value="1" {% if "selecone" in decision_results %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}/>
                selecone
              </label>

              <label class="dropdown-option">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Selection Two" value="1" {% if "Selection Two" in decision_results %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}/>
                Selection Two
              </label>

              <label class="dropdown-option">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Selection Three" value="1" {% if "Selection Three" in decision_results %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}/>
                Selection Three
              </label>

              <label class="dropdown-option">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Selection Four" value="1" {% if "Selection Four" in decision_results %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}/>
                Selection Four
              </label>

              <label class="dropdown-option">
                <input type="checkbox" name="Selection Five" value="1" {% if "Selection Five" in decision_results %} checked {% else %} {% endif %}/>
                Selection Five
              </label>     
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button style="background-color: #4A9FFF; border-color: #4A9FFF; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 0; padding: 0.85rem 1.05rem; font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.25;" onclick="changeFlag()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Buscar"> 
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: you could assign the values from your query string to html hidden inputs in the form...that way they will get passed the 2nd time

Comment: Yes, the URL part left of the `?` is the location, and submitting a 2nd GET form will ignore everything else.

Answer (score 0):

The form will only submit the fields that belong to it (i.e. inside the `<form>`). If you want to repeat the search with the new form inputs added, you can add an `<input type="hidden">` with the `value` that you get from the GET request to the side form (second one).

So let's say you get the `termo_busca` from the URL, then you can add:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{termo}}" name="termo_busca" />
```

to your second form. And so on, for the other search parameters you want to repeat.

You should only add an `<input type="hidden">` for each parameter you want to repeat in the second search **as-is** (i.e. the user won't modify it).

If you want the user to be able to modify it in the `diogo_form`, then you should add the corresponding `input` with the correct type (e.g. `checkbox`).

So if you want to repeat the `recursal` checkbox in the second form, you would add this line from the first form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="recursal" value="1" {% if "recursal" in params %} checked {% endif %}> Recursal
```

Note that you would check for `recursal` in the GET parameters.

Also, note that I removed the `{% else %}` since it wasn't doing anything there.

---

**UPDATE:**

Like I said, the `form` will only submit the values that it contains. If you don't want to repeat the checkboxes then you need a javascript solution that will "add" these values to your second form on submit or will mirror them.

Here is a solution using jQuery and adding them before you submit:

```
$('#diogo_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let recursal_val = $('#search_form input[name="recursal"]').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
    $('#diogo_form').append(`<input type="hidden" name="recursal" value="${recursal_val}" />`);

    // ... do the same for all other values you want to copy
    // you could potentially also copy them all if you want them all
    // $('#search_form input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, e) {
    //   let name = $(e).attr('name');
    //   let checked = $(e).is(':checked');
    //   if(checked) {
    //     // add to diogo_form (see above)
    //   }
    // });

    $('#diogo_form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Hey, this works one step further! Now I'm only having trouble with the checkboxes from the first forms, like for "recursal". It works for the search term and second checkboxes or for the search term and first checkboxes but not all three at the same time...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, when you submit the `diogo_form` you don't get the checkbox values for the original (`search_form`) request? Did you put similar `hidden` inputs for the checkboxes as well?

Comment: I tried to, not sure if I did it right,
<input type="hidden" value="{{}}" name="recursal" />
if I put anything in the value up there it stays locked on that variable, no matter if the checkbox is checked or not, if I leave it empty then the variable doesnt work and checking the box doesnt do anything...

Comment: That creates a second checkbox, i only want the one on the first forms, then I want the button on the second forms to not ignore the selection of the checkboxes of the first one. This way the checkboxes on the second forms work like a filter for the results of the first ones.